# Permission denied when trying to do mysqldump of local database

Tags: mysql, terminal

I want to backup my local `MySQL` database by using the MAC Terminal but when I enter:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -uroot -p localdev > localdev.sql
```

I get the error: `Permission denied`

I tried to add a password to my local `phpmyadmin` so that the password for the root user is 123456 but when I entered:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -uroot -p123456 localdev > localdev.sql
```

I get the same error!?!

I'm using MAMP, so can that be a reason it fails?

Please help

Comment: Are you trying to output the file in a directory where you don't have permission to write new files? Try `touch localdev.sql` and see if you get the same error.

Comment: @BillKarwin There is no difference - I get the same error

Comment: What's the full error message? There's a difference between the mysql permission denied and the file system permission denied.

Comment: @aynber I get `-bash localdev.sql:Permission denied` - thats all

Comment: Then I agree with Bill Karwin, it's a file permission error. If you cannot write any file to that folder (the `touch` fails) check the permissions on the folder, or try writing to a different location. Also if there's already a file with that name, try writing to a different filename `touch localdev2.sql`

Comment: try writing the file to a directory where you do have permissions, e.g. on mac and  linux, you probably have permission on `/tmp` directory ... e.g.   `> /tmp/localdev.sql`.  if you are attempting to execute a script, make sure that the  execute permission has been set on the script file ... `chmod ug+x myscript.sh`

Comment: @spencer7593 Now I get `No such file or directory` when I try `> /tmp/localdev.sql` :-/

Comment: Try your home directory, either with `cd ~` before the command, or write to `localdev > ~/localdev.sql`

Answer (score 3):

You need a space between -u and username, like this:

```
/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqldump -u root -p123456 localdev > localdev.sql
```

Space between -p and password DONT need

Comment: what about the -p option?

Comment: -p dont need a space

Comment: i know that, but maybe OP doesn't. Or someone that will read this answer later will not. Your answer should be complete and a reference

Answer (score 0):

Allright, I found out tHAT I needed to change the path to:

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysqldump -u root -p123456 localdev > localdev.sql
```

This solved it :-)

Thanks for all your help anyway!